# Error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname on render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, render

I created an API using nodejs and express with sequelize as the ORM.The entry point of my API is backend/app.js and it has the following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();
const db = require('./db/models');
const { port } = require('./config');
const { environment } = require('./config');

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use(routes);
const isProduction = environment === 'production';
//console.log(environment);
db.sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log('Database connection success! Sequelize is ready to use...');
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Database connection failure.');
  console.error(err);
});
module.exports = app;
```

my daatabase connection is defined like in backend/config/database.js and it looks like this.

```
const config = require('./index');
  module.exports = {
  development: {
    url:config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    seederStorage: 'sequelize'
  }
  
},
  
production: {
    url: config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    seederStorage: 'sequelize',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

It obtains the environment variables from backend/config/index.js which looks like this.

```
module.exports = {
    environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production',
    port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
    url:process.env.DB_DATABASE_URL,
    db: {
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST
    },
    jwtConfig: {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
    }
  };
```

Here is the file sequelize prepoluted for me when i did `npx sequelize init`

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../../config/database.js')[env];
const db = {};


const sequelize = new Sequelize(`${config.url}`,config);

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Now when I connected to an external postgres database on render locally everything worked.But when I try to do the same on production I keep getting this error

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND hostname
Jun 17 01:58:00 PM        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:67:26) {
Jun 17 01:58:00 PM      errno: -3008,
Jun 17 01:58:00 PM      code: 'ENOTFOUND',
Jun 17 01:58:00 PM      syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
```

on checking my render database logs I saw this.

```
[648db748.3fb9b2-2] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=::1,LOG:  connection authenticated: identity="postgres" method=md5 (/pgdata/host name.conf:90)
Jun 17 02:38:16 PM  [648db748.3fb9b2-3] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=[unknown],client=::1,LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres application_name=psql SSL enabled 
Jun 17 02:38:16 PM  [648db748.3fb9b2-4] user=postgres,db=postgres,app=psql,client=::1,LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:00.046 user=postgres database=postgres host=::1 port=48998
```

I am quite new to nodejs/express and will appraciate any help I can get,I equally connected to my external database locally and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using render's external Postgres database URL solved this problem, as opposed to the inner one I was previously using.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small mistake in your config file:

```js
const config = require('./index');
  module.exports = {
  development: {
    url:config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    seederStorage: 'sequelize'
  }
  
},
  
production: {
    url: config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    seederStorage: 'sequelize',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

should actually be:

```js
const config = require('./index');
module.exports = {
  development: {
    url:config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      },
    seederStorage: 'sequelize'
  },
  production: {
    url: config.url,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    seederStorage: 'sequelize',
    dialectOptions: {
      ssl: {
        require: false,
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Only the exported variables / objects will be available when imported in your other files. Most likely this is why it was not being able to resolve the DNS for the production host.

Comment: Please let me know if this solved the issue and then mark it as accepted answer so that others can find it in the future. Let me know if it did not solve the issue. Since I don't have information here about where your production setup is hosted this is all I can think of at this point.

Comment: No, it did not solve the problem, thank you so much for helping. I discovered that I was using the internal render database URL, hence the error, everything worked fine when I switched to the external Postgres URL.

Comment: Okay. All good, as long as you got your issue solved. Maybe write that as an answer to your own question.